# Description of irreducible representations of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho: SL(2,\mathbb R) \to GL(V)$ be an irreducible representation of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$. [A paper I am reading says](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603483.pdf#page=8#) $\rho$ can be described as a symmetric tensor product in $Sym^n(\mathbb R^2)$, which has $A^n, A^{n-1}B,\dots, B^n$ as a basis (over $\mathbb R$), where $A=(1,0)^T$ and $B=(0,1)^T$.

But I am very confused about how this is actually connected to a representation $\rho: SL(2,\mathbb R) \to GL(V)$. Say if I have a homogeneous polynomial

$$p(A,B):=c_0 A^n + c_1 A^{n-1}B + \cdots c_n B^n,$$

then how can we view $p(A,B)$ as a representation
$\rho: SL(2,\mathbb R) \to GL(V)$ literally?

It would be great if someone could also show me some reference to the proof of this result

Comment: Did you read Gelfand and Naimark's book?

Comment: @JCAA which book?

Comment: There are only a few books by these authors. Gelfand, I. M.; Neumark, M. A.
Unitäre Darstellungen der klassischen Gruppen. (German) Akademie-Verlag, Berlin, 1957. XL+333 pp.

is one of them.  There is also a much newer book by Lang: Lang, Serge(1-YALE)
SL2(R).
Reprint of the 1975 edition. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 105. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1985. xiv+428 pp. ISBN: 0-387-96198-4


Which is a reprint of Lang, Serge
SL2(R). Addison-Wesley Publishing Co., Reading, Mass.-London-Amsterdam, 1975. xvi+428 pp.

Answer (score 1):

So $V$ is the set of homogeneous polynomials in $A$ and $B$ of degree $n$, so is a vector
space of dimension $n+1$.

So how does $\text{SL}_2(\Bbb R)$ act on this? Let $f(A,B)\in V$ and $M=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\in \text{SL}_2(\Bbb R)$. Then $M$ takes $f$ to $f(aA+bB,cA+dB)$.